# How can I create custom Tabs with multiple labels per tab in material UI?

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I'm using material UI, `material-ui/Tabs` Code sample like this...

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar'
import Tabs, { Tab } from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

const styles = theme => ({
  bigIndicator: {
    height: 5,
  },
});

class BasicTabs extends React.Component {
  state = { value: 0 }

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const {value} = this.state

    return [
      <AppBar position="static" key="appbar">
        <Tabs 
          classes={{ indicator: classes.bigIndicator }} 
          value={value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <Tab label="T1 Label 1" />
          <Tab label="T2 Label 1" />
          <Tab label="T3 Label 1" />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>,
      <div key="tab-content">
        {value === 0 && <Typography>Item One</Typography>}
        {value === 1 && <Typography>Item Two</Typography>}
        {value === 2 && <Typography>Item Three</Typography>}
      </div>
    ]
  }
}

BasicTabs.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(BasicTabs);
```

But I want to add label 2 in each tab so that this should look similar to this...
[image]

This is my Example codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/xjj5j6284

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The label can be as complex as you need it to be. For example:

```
          <Tab
            label={
              <React.Fragment>
                T1 Label 1<br />
                <span style={{ fontSize: "smaller" }}>T1 Label2</span>
              </React.Fragment>
            }
          />
```

[image: Edit Material UI - Customizing tab indicator]

One side note is that I want to make sure you are aware that you are using a very old version of Material-UI. The imports for the current version start with "@material-ui/core" instead of "material-ui".

So instead of

```
import { withStyles } from "material-ui/styles";
import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import Tabs, { Tab } from "material-ui/Tabs";
import Typography from "material-ui/Typography";
```

you should have

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
```

Comment: Thank you, Ryan, `React.Fragment` worked. Yes, that example I shared from material-UI example so it's old, but in my real application, it's already updated.

Comment: In my project it could be use <> </>. Thank a lot